# Sparse diagonal matrix from sparse diagonal blocks

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to have a sparse `n x n` matrix `A`, where `B` is a `m x m` sparse matrix and `n = m * m`:

[image]

I know how to make `B`:

```
 data = np.vstack([-np.ones(n), 4 * np.ones(n), -np.ones(n)])
 diag = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
 B = scipy.sparse.spdiags(data, diag, m, m).tocsr()
```

and of course how to make the identity `I`. Somehow, I cannot do the same to make `A`.

I know how to do it in a dumb way: substitute all numbers from `B` into `A` and make `A` with 5 diagonals in the same way, as   `B` was made. But I do believe that  `scipy.sparse`  can do this simpler.

I already spent two hours thinking about it, maybe finding a simpler approach just isn't worth of it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a `sparse.block_diag` function.

```
In [383]: n,m=3,3                                                                                        
In [385]: data = np.vstack([-np.ones(n), 4 * np.ones(n), -np.ones(n)]).astype(int) 
     ...: diag = np.array([-1, 0, 1]) 
     ...: B = sparse.spdiags(data, diag, m, m).tocsr()                                                   
In [386]: B                                                                                              
Out[386]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [387]: B.A                                                                                            
Out[387]: 
array([[ 4, -1,  0],
       [-1,  4, -1],
       [ 0, -1,  4]], dtype=int64)
In [388]: I = -sparse.eye(m).astype(int)
```

`block_diag` doesn't have an offset feature, so I'll first combine the `B` and `I` into a larger block.

```
In [389]: M1 = sparse.bmat([[B,I],[I,B]])                                                                
In [390]: M1                                                                                             
Out[390]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [391]: M1.A                                                                                           
Out[391]: 
array([[ 4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0],
       [-1,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  4,  0,  0, -1],
       [-1,  0,  0,  4, -1,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0, -1,  4, -1],
       [ 0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  4]], dtype=int64)
In [392]: M2 =sparse.block_diag((M1,M1))                                                                 
In [393]: M2                                                                                             
Out[393]: 
<12x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 40 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [394]: M2.A                                                                                           
Out[394]: 
array([[ 4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  4,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  4, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0, -1,  4, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  4,  0,  0, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  4, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  4, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  4]], dtype=int64)
```

Look at the `block_mat` code; it constructs a nested list of inputs and `None`, and passes that to `bmat`.  And the code of `bmat` combines the `coo` attributes of all inputs with suitable offsets, making `coo` style inputs for the result matrix. `sparse.hstack` and `sparse.vstack` are other examples using `bmat`.

So following those models you could construct your composite directly from `B` and `I`.

===

5 diagonals directly:

```
In [405]: data = -np.ones((5,12),int)                                                                    
In [406]: data[0,:] *= -4                                                                                
In [407]: offsets=np.array([0,-1,-3,1,3])  # offsets dont have to be in order                                                         
In [408]: M4 = sparse.spdiags(data, offsets,12,12)                                                       
In [409]: M4                                                                                             
Out[409]: 
<12x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 52 stored elements (5 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
In [410]: M4.A                                                                                           
Out[410]: 
array([[ 4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0, -1,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0, -1,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  4, -1,  0, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  4, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  4, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  4]])
```

Direct to `coo` inputs:

```
In [411]: data,rows,cols = [],[],[]  
In [413]: for v,z in zip([-1,-1,4,-1,-1],[-3,-1,0,1,3]): 
     ...:    len = 12-abs(z) 
     ...:    d = np.ones(len, int)*v 
     ...:    r = np.arange(len)+max(0,z) 
     ...:    c = np.arange(len)+max(0,-z) 
     ...:    data.append(d); rows.append(r); cols.append(c) 
     ...:                                                                                                
In [414]: data                                                                                           
Out[414]: 
[array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]),
 array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]),
 array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]),
 ...]
In [415]: rows                                                                                           
Out[415]: 
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),
 array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]),
 ....]
In [416]: cols                                                                                           
Out[416]: 
[array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]),
 array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]),
 ...]
In [417]: M5 = sparse.coo_matrix((np.hstack(data), (np.hstack(rows), np.hstack(cols))))                  
In [418]: M5                                                                                             
Out[418]: 
<12x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 52 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Or just with the `data` list (and offsets):

```
In [427]: M6=sparse.diags(data, [-3,-1,0,1,3],dtype=int,format='csr')                                 
In [428]: M6                                                                                          
Out[428]: 
<12x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 52 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the elements of diagonals with offsets -3 and 3 should be just -1, without any zeros. Also for 3 by 3 `B` the size of the final matrix `A` (or `M2` in your notation) must be 9 by 9. I am not sure yet how to do this properly, but anyway I will try to use your approach. And thanks for `B.A`, that is so cool. I always used `B.toarray()`

Comment: Maybe you could make a separate matrix with those -1 diagonals and add that.  But it wouldn't be hard (or any slower) to fill the 5 diagonals directly in `coo` style arrays (or lists).

Comment: Exactly, and I thought that for such a basic thing there should be some simple way to do it.

Comment: I added a couple of other constructions.